# ExpansionTile has performance issues

Tags: flutter, user-interface

When I try to create my ExpansionTile's with grouped data, the performance suffers drastically.

```
 // Variable: Group the data by the flagMora field
              final groupedData = groupBy(
                state.clientsToContact!.data!,
                (ClientsToContactData element) => element.flagMora,
              );

              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: groupedData.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int group) {
                  return ExpansionTile(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent.withOpacity(0.1),
                    title: Text(groupedData.keys.elementAt(group)),
                    children: groupedData.values.elementAt(group).map((client) {
                      return ListTile(
                        minVerticalPadding: 20,
                        title: Text(client.cliente),
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.person_rounded),
                        trailing: Text(
                          // Si flagMora tiene números, se muestra la G

                          (client.flagMora.contains(RegExp('[0-9]')))
                              ? '${client.flagMora} G'
                              : client.flagMora,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
                        ),
                        subtitle: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '\$ ${client.saldoVencido.toStringAsFixed(2).replaceAllMapped(
                                    RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'),
                                    (match) => '${match[1]},',
                                  )}',
                            ),
                            Text(
                              client.convenio,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        // Agrega más información del cliente aquí
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                },
              );
```

I want to know if there is another more efficient way to get a similar UI but with better performance.

I tried a Listview Builder in the list of the expansiontile but the performance has not been affected.

Comment: Is there a way to prepare your data, for example run `RegExp` and `replaceAllMapped` outside the `build` method? If the values don't change between builds it can help. Also have you tried performance in release or profile build? Debug builds are much slower.

Comment: Thanks, I format the data in the bloc but the problem persist